# Update query is not working in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing one phonegap application which sync with online storage. For that I need an update query. I wrote but not working as expected. Here I have given my code for updating from json data.

```
function SyncUpdate(id)
{
    db.transaction(syncUpdateData);
    alert("SyncUpdate Called..."+id);
    function syncUpdateData(tx)
    {
        //alert(id);
        $.post("http://testwebsite.com/DailyWord/GetWordByID.php",{ID:id},function(data){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json, function() 
            {
            alert('UPDATE DW_Words SET word="'+this['Word']+'",explanation="'+this['Explanation']+'",usage="'+this['Usage']+'",tags="'+this['Tags']+'",date="'+this['Date']+'" WHERE id="'+this['ID']+'"');
            tx.executeSql('UPDATE DW_Words SET word="'+this['Word']+'",explanation="'+this['Explanation']+'",usage="'+this['Usage']+'",tags="'+this['Tags']+'",date="'+this['Date']+'" WHERE id="'+this['ID']+'"');
            });
            alert('Update Query Fiured');           
        });

    }
}
```

Here I am receiving data from json and value for variable id as expected. Please help me to do this.

Comment: The alert giving me correct query but its not executing...

Comment: Tried with no luck shailendr...

Comment: could  you make one jsfiddle for this question so i can check with other possibilities.

Comment: THOUGHTS: First of all, it is documented that `$.each` is at least 100 times slower than native JS `for()`. Additionally I would use `console.log(json)` to make sure you are iterating the correct array. You may need to be iterating a sub of `json` and that could be the issue.

Comment: 1) Be sure that you execute the code after the `deviceready`event 2) use the callbacks for executeSql, if an error occurs you can print it and understand what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, order of operations gets in the mix of these things, I would try something more like this:

```
function SyncUpdate(id)
{
    $.post("http://testwebsite.com/DailyWord/GetWordByID.php",{ID:id},function(data){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        var len = json.length;
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                tx.executeSql('UPDATE DW_Words SET word="'+json[i]['Word']+'",explanation="'+json[i]['Explanation']+'",usage="'+json[i]['Usage']+'",tags="'+json[i]['Tags']+'",date="'+json[i]['Date']+'" WHERE id="'+json[i]['ID']+'"');
            }
        });
    });
}
```